# How to associate the Pardot visitor ID with form submission

Tags: pardot

We are using Drupal forms on our website that process submitted form data before sending it via POST form action to Pardot endpoint url. The Pardot visitor ID is therefore not associated with the created/updated Pardot prospect.

We do not redirect to a thank you page but show a success message with ajax.

Does anyone know a solid solution to this?

Cheers!
Clausule

Answer (score 0):

If the visitor's browser is making the URL request to Pardot's Form Handler, the visitor association will happen automatically.

If Drupal is making a server-side submission, that explains what you are seeing. You have a couple of options:

1. See if you can adjust your flow so that the visitor's browser actually makes the Form Handler request sending cookies and all that fun. It might break your desire to have an ajax success message...but it will be the easiest.
2. You might be able to send the user to a URL on your website appending the URL Query Parameter `pi_list_email` which will also cause the visitor association. There are some potential considerations by putting the visitor's Email in the URL (especially if you are using Analytics etc)
3. Your server-side processing could make a Pardot API request to do the visitor association. This is the most complex, as you will need to deal with Salesforce's oAuth protocol in addition to getting the Prospect ID for your visitor after the Form Handler is submitted.